# Is the site association bonus taken into account for Brunhilde hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, association-bonus, winter-bash-2018

The [Brunhilde hat](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/brunhilde) is described as:

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

Does the *+100 site association bonus* count towards the required 150?

Comment: @Glorfindel Okay, so, thanks to Ankit Sharma asking this in 2016, it does not count now :D Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't count"? It's upvoted, it's not going to be deleted and users who have this question will fin the answer.

Comment: @Catija I mean the association bonus does not count towards the hat. But yeah, the question is fine in this state. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! my mistake! :)

Comment: @Catija no problem, although, I'd be happy for this question to be downvoted a few times. You know, for no reason :)

Comment: ... no reason at all ;)